# How to loop over a deep nested dict structure with Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, devops, administration

i get stuck at a maybe easy task on ansible. I have a deep nested dict
with 3 levels:

```
---
postgres:
  user: postgres
  password: test123
  hosts:
    - host: localhost
      user: postgres
      password: test123
      users:
        - user: bm
          password: 123
          databases:
            - bm
            - bm2
        - user: bm_test
          password: 123
          databases:
            - bm_test

filebeat:
  - document_type: syslog
    paths:
      - /var/log/syslog
```

now Ansible creates a new user:

```
- name: create postgres users
  postgresql_user:
    login_host: "{{ item.0.host }}"
    login_user: "{{ item.0.user }}"
    login_password: "{{ item.0.password }}"
    name: "{{ item.1.user }}"
    password: "{{ item.1.password }}"
    encrypted: yes
    # priv: "CONNECT/products:ALL"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ postgres.hosts|default([]) }}"
    - users
```

now the point where i stuck:

```
- name: create databases
  postgresql_db:
    login_host: "{{ item.0.host }}"
    login_user: "{{ item.0.user }}"
    login_password: "{{ item.0.password }}"
    name: "{{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ postgres.hosts|default([]) | sum(attribute='users', start=[]) | list }}"
    - databases
```

The Problem here is item.0.host, user & password is not defined. What could i do?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: So you want to create databases based on data specifying user-to-db assignment? Looping problem aside, it looks like a strange design to me.

Comment: i am open for suggestions on the design.

Comment: ansible should be able to create the users and databases from the list, the user should only have access to the databases in the nested databases list.